# Is Google Analytics Secure to Track Business Application Usage?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, usage-statistics

I have recently been required to implement some Usage Tracking to a web-based Business Application. Basically what needs to be tracked is what pages in the application are being used and for how long users stay on those pages. The application is hosted on the internet and is HTML/JavaScript.

I could use Google Analytics to track page views, visits and browser capabilities, but is it secure enough to use for business applications?

Does anyone else use Google Analytics to track web-based business application usage? Or do you have some thoughts on this?

Also, I couldn't find anything from Google specifically stating whether this is a good or bad thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to be secure.

Gathered data, if you trust Google, is pretty secure.

However, Analytics data can be tampered with. Someone can read your Analytics ID from page source (or HTTP traffic) and submit fake pageviews, events, change custom variables, etc.